# Show that if $Q \notin m$, $Q$ ideal,$m$ maximal ideal then $\phi(Q)R_m=R_m$

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

Show that if $Q \notin m$, $Q$ ideal,$m$ maximal ideal then $\phi(Q)R_m=R_m$.

$R_m$ is the localisation. $\phi$ is the homomorphism from $R$ to $R_m$ sending $r$ to $r/1$

This is the actual question:
[Inducing homomorphisms on localizations of rings/modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683104/inducing-homomorphisms-on-localizations-of-rings-modules)

I basically need to know:

If $M$ does not contain $I_k$, we have $(I_k)_M=R_M$ because $I_k∩(R∖M)≠∅$. Why does this reason imply $(I_k)M=R_M$(this is what I'm asking above I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably $Q\not\subset m$. In this case, take $q\in Q$, $q\notin m$; then $q/1$ belongs to $\phi(Q)R_m$ and is invertible.

Comment: Why does the last bit show $\phi(Q) R_m=R_m$?

Comment: @Bob If an ideal contains an invertible element, it is the whole ring.